# Using MySQL on Openshift with Symfony 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, openshift

I added MySQL, and PHPMyAdmin cartridges to my openshift php app. 
After mysql cartridge was added I saw the page which says:

```
Connection URL: mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
```

but I have no idea what does it mean.

When I access mysql database through PHPMyAdmin, 
I see 127.8.111.1 as db host, so I configured my symfony 2 app (parameters.yml):

```
parameters:    
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     127.8.111.1
    database_port:     3306
    database_name:     <some_database>
    database_user:     admin
    database_password: <some_password>
```

Now when I access my web page it throws an error, which I believe related to mysql connection. Can someone show me proper way of doing the above?

EDIT: It seems mysql connection works fine, but somehow

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error
```

is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The code I use and works very well to make my apps working both on localhost and openshift without changing database config parameters every time I move between them is this:

```
<?php
# app/config/params.php
if (getEnv("OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME")!='') {
    $container->setParameter('database_host', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"));
    $container->setParameter('database_port', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"));
    $container->setParameter('database_name', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME"));
    $container->setParameter('database_user', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
    $container->setParameter('database_password', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));
}?>
```

*This will tell the app that if is openshift environment it needs to load different username, host, database, etc.*

Then you have to import this file (params.php) from your `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: params.php }
...
```

And that's it. You will never have to touch this file or parameters.yml when you move on openshift or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection URL: mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/
```

OpenShift exposes environment variables to your application containing the host and port information for your database.  You should reference these environment variables in your configuration instead of hard-coding values.  I am not a Symfony expert, but it looks to me like you would need to do the following in order to use this information in your app:

Create a pre-start hook for your application and export variables in Symfony's expected format.  Add the following to the .openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_php-5.3 file in your application's git repo:

```
export SYMFONY__DATABASE__HOST=$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST
export SYMFONY__DATABASE__PORT=$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT
```

[Symphony uses this pattern to identify external configuration in the environment](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html), and will make the this configuration available for use in your YAML configuration:

```
parameters:    
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     "%database.host%"
    database_port:     "%database.port%"
```

EDIT:

Another option to expose this information for use in the YAML configuration is to import a php file in your app/config/config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

In app/config/parameters.php:

```
$container->setParameter('database.host', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"));
$container->setParameter('database.port', getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"));
```

Comment: It says: You have requested a non-existent parameter "database.host".

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about what steps you took?